# Rails: how to customize text_method in options_from_collection_for_select when collection was built with a inner join statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, customization

I have a collection built with a Myclass.joins().where() statement.

The problem I have is when I want to customize the text_method in:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@collection,"id", custom_text_method)
```

My problem is that @collection items are not a instance of Myclass, but only a instance of Class.

Thanks for any hints!
Markus

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I just changed the name of each @collection item in the controller.

That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

you can define a method in specify model,
for example, there are two column in user table. one is first name, the other is last name. show full name as text_method.

```
def full_name
  "#{self.last_name}, #{self.first_name}"
end
```

in `options_from_collection_for_select`,text_method param use `full_name`:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(collections, "id","full_name")
```